# What is the enviroment when exec the kernel code

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel

for x86, the kernel is loaded by bios at 0x7c00 and exec there. 
I am not familiar with the kernel image and confused of the enviroment when exec at 0x7c00. I am recently rearch the ELF format and know there are many sectors in a loadable file, the ld load the ELF file and init the enviroment when procedure exec. But for the kernel boot case, what happened?

Comment: You mean the boot sector is loaded there?  The BIOS can't load a whole kernel unless it's tiny, that's why we use bootloaders (http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootloader) like GRUB.  Or in the old days, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_(boot_loader)

Comment: See [the GRUB documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-documentation.html) to learn more about the state it has the machine in when it jumps to the kernel it loaded.

Comment: The kernel is almost never at 0x7c00.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the kernel is not loaded at 0x7c00 by the BIOS or firmware, but the "bootloader" is loaded there. On x86/IA32 systems, the initial environment of system software is 16-bit mode (called real-mode proper). In real-mode, to access memory, code uses a segment:offset memory addressing system. This allows linear addresses of more than 16-bit size to be used.

The BIOS has no notion of a filesystem for the bootloader. Only 512 bytes, from the boot sector of the disk, are loaded and copied at the 0x7c00 address. The code must  be ready to execute there without any relocations/linkage, because BIOS does not know any of that. Also the entry for the bootloader must be at 0x7c00 only, and thus elf-files (which contain a header at the very starting) cannot be loaded because code is not located at the starting. So, the bootloader is in the form of a raw binary.

BIOS provides services for using devices on the system using the

```
int <systemCallIndex>
```

instruction, which those 512 bytes loaded must use to loader other sectors on the disk. This is a very low-level task, which can be very buggy. Programming in userspace is very easy compared to here.

Note that the bootloader-file may be of any size, but the first 512-bytes will be loaded by BIOS. Thus, this code will load other sectors on the disk.

**Kernel Loading by the Bootloader:**

The bootloader setups the system for use by the kernel. Advanced bootloaders like GRUB, can even load elf-files & read normal filesystems (like FAT). Thus, the kernel gets a much higher level environment than the bootloader. Some loaders, like GRUB2 allow loading other kernel-modules & setting up protected mode for the kernel.

For more in-depth information, visit osdev.org

Comment: And this applies only for legacy BIOS booting, not when booting in EFI mode like modern PCs.

Comment: I have mentioned that BIOS works like this, but haven't mentioned about EFI.